# Complex Case Statement Issue - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Wrote the query below, but am getting multiplied amounts because the aggregation needs to occur before the case statements. Would love some advice on the best way to structure this.

```
Select Store, CUSTID, CUST.ID_CUST,

 Sum(
  CASE  
    WHEN Cust_Gift.Code_Status = 'C' AND Gift_Item.FLAG_STORE_LOC = 'N'
    THEN Cust_Gift.AMT_PAID ELSE 0 
  END) GiftAmt,

 Sum(
  CASE WHEN Cust_Gift.Code_Status = 'C' AND Gift_Item.FLAG_STORE_LOC  = 'Y'
   THEN Cust_Gift.AMT ELSE 0 
  END) CustGiftAmt,

Sum(
  CASE WHEN Cust_Coupon.Code_Status = 'C' 
   THEN Cust_Coupon.AMT
   ELSE 0 
  END) CouponAmt,

Sum(CASE WHEN Cust_Sports.Status = 'C' 
  THEN Cust_Sports.AMT
  ELSE 0 
END) SportsAmt

FROM CUST
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CUST_GIFT
   ON CUST.ID_CUST = CUST_GIFT.ID_CUST
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CUST_COUPON 
   ON CUST.ID_CUST = CUST_COUPON.ID_CUST
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CUST_SPORTS
   ON CUST.ID_CUST = CUST_SPORTS.ID_CUST
  INNER JOIN GIFT_ITEM
   ON CUST_GIFT.ID_GIFT_ITEM = GIFT_ITEM.ID_GIFT_ITEM

WHERE (STORE = 'M669098' OR STORE = 'M66923434' )

Group by CustID, Store, CUST.ID_CUST
```

Comment: Your joins are multiplying the number of rows.  You need to aggregate *before* doing the joins.

Comment: You can do the aggregation inside a subquery, and then join this result back to your original query.

Comment: Get rid of GIFT_ITEM join and you will be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way you could do it:

```
SELECT cust.store,
       cust.custid,
       cust.id_cust,
       gift.giftamt,
       gift.custgift,
       cpn.couponamt,
       sprt.sportsamt
FROM   cust
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id_cust,
                               SUM(CASE WHEN cg.code_status = 'C' AND gi.flag_store_loc = 'N' THEN cg.amt_paid END) giftamt,
                               SUM(CASE WHEN cg.code_status = 'C' AND gi.flag_store_loc = 'Y' THEN cg.amt_paid END) custgiftamt
                        FROM   cust_gift cg
                               INNER JOIN gift_item gi ON cg.id_gift_item = gi.id_gift_item) gift ON cust.id_cust = gift.id_cust
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id_cust,
                               SUM(CASE WHEN code_status = 'C' THEN amt END) couponamt
                        FROM   cust_coupon) cpn ON cust.id_cust = cpn.id_cust
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id_cust,
                               SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'C' THEN amt END) sportsamt
                        FROM   cust_sports) sprt ON cust.id_cust = sprt.id_cust
WHERE  (STORE = 'M669098' OR STORE = 'M66923434');
```

Comment: For the line (CASE WHEN code_status = 'C' AND flag_store_loc = 'Y' THEN amt_paid END) custgiftamt FROM   cust_gift cg) - those two fields are from different tables, but you only have one join statement. How would i include two different join statements to flag both fields? (code_status and flag_store_loc)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that. Simply create another outer join based on that extra join condition and do the sum there, similar to the coupon/sports subquery joins

Comment: I'll take another look at this when I'm back in the office tomorrow. What's the relationship between the two gift tables? Is it one-one or one-many, based on your join condition?

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer - it wasn't so difficult, you just needed an extra join in the gift subquery.

Comment: Appreciate it! Thanks for the help & revision